# VB 6.0: How can I see XML variables in Immediate Window

Tags: xml, vb6

I am debugging a VB 6.0 program that is using XML methods, etc. How can I see how these XML variables look in my program when I am debugging it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use watch window (view menu -> watch window or locals window) or immediate window, when you are debugging or hit a breakpoint.

Inside immediate window ( <kbd>ctrl  + g</kbd> ), type `? myXmlVariable` to see the content of the variable named `myXmlVariable`.

Comment: Ok, good Call,... I will use the Watch window...
The Immediate Windows does not work that way.. gives error.. I wish there was a way that I could type my XML variable in it and then it could show the XML structure for it ... that is what I am looking for ...

Comment: You will have to type in a property name or a method that returns a value. for your example, it can be `Debug.Print oNode.InnerXml` where `InnerXml` is the property of the node. In the immediate window, you will have to type `? oNode.InnerXml`. From what I know, there is no XML visualizer available for VB6 IDE.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `Debug.Print myXmlVariable` in the code and it will automatically write to the immediate window as it encounters the code during run time or as you are stepping through it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it now .. again it gives error" Object does not support this method "..or  something like that 
------------
  Dim oNode As IXMLDOMNode

  Set oNode = XMLNewChildNode(oParent, sName, oParent.namespaceURI)

  Debug.Print (oNode)

Comment: you can't use it to print the "object" of onode, you have to output a property.  e.g.  "Debug.Print oNode.InnerXml" or "Debug.Print  oNode.Value"